# Groups of Order 2 with subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let G be an abelian group and $a,b\in G$ be two distinct elements with a and b or order $2$.

1. Show that $H=\{e,a,b,ab\}$ forms a subgroup and write out its multiplication table.
2. Justify why all the elements in $H$ must be distinct.
3. Prove that $$K=\{g \in G  : |g| \leq 2\}.$$ Show that this can fail if $G$ is not abelian.

I can do part 1 (show $H$ has associativity, inverses, closure, and the identity element), but for parts 2 and 3 how do I show distinctness, assume two are equal and make a contradiction? Because I can't see how that will get me somewhere. And for 3, where do I begin?

Comment: What is $K$ here?

Comment: For (2), assuming two are equal and deriving a contradiction would be efficient---there are only four elements, so there are very few cases, and all of them are easy.

Comment: K is some group that has been created. Dont know why

Comment: also are those cases for 2, e=a, a=b, and a=ab?

Comment: Along with $ab = e$, and the observation that the $e = b$ and $b = ab$ cases follow by symmetry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$G$ have $4$ elements, one of which must be the unit $e$ and there
must be another element $e\neq a\in G$.

Now, there is another element in the group $b$ with $b\neq a$
and $b\neq e$ .

Finally, consider the element $ab\in G$: 
$$
ab=a\implies a^{-1}ab=a^{-1}a\implies b=e
$$

which is false. 
$$
ab=b\implies abb^{-1}=bb^{-1}\implies a=e
$$

which is also false.

and 
$$
ab=e\implies b=a^{-1}
$$

but $a$ is of order $2$ so $a=a^{-1}$ and thus $b=a$ which is
again false.

We conclude $ab$ is the fourth element in $G$.

If I understood what part $3$ is asking you: Consider the Dihedral
group of a square $G=D_{8}$,

We have it that $D_{8}=\langle s,rs\rangle$ since $r=rs\cdot s\in\langle s,rs\rangle$
but although $s,rs$ are both of order $2$ 
$$
G\neq K=\{g\in G\mid|g|\leq2\}
$$

since $r\in D_{8}$ is of order $4$.

Comment: @Jack - it is uncleared what asked, but I added an answer for that assuming I guessed what the question meant

Comment: i saw ythat right after i posted that comment. but could you just explain it in more words?

Comment: @Jack -What don't you understand ?

Comment: after: the but althought s,rs are both of order 2, G is not equal to K

Comment: @Jack - If $G$ is abelian and $a,b$ are distinct of order $2$ then then
$H=\langle a,b\rangle$ is a subgroup of order $4$. But if $G$ is
not abelian then $\langle a,b\rangle$ can have more elements in it,
as I demonstrated using $D_{8}$
. If that not what part 3 wanted you to do, then I don't understand the question itself

Comment: honestly not even I fully understand the question so thank you